# How To Update MySql Values By Using One Click In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a web site. So , there is a table to show users. In my database, I stored 0 for the Pending and 1 for the Approved under Action column. If some user has 0 , Pending will be displayed in this table and if the user has 1 Approved will be displayed. Now I want to when someone clicks this Pending button, I want to update database value to 1. I tried it as below. But , when I click Pending button, it gives me this error -

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

In my address bar of web browser, I got the correct Id like this - `http://localhost/cheapfares/invoice/approvededit/49`

And also I was unable to update the database value.

How Can I Fix this ??

View Page. ( all-invoice.blade.com )

```
@if($Invoice->invoicestatus =="Pending")
<td><a href="approvededit/{{ $Invoice->invoicereference }}"><input type="submit" name="pending" value="Pending" class="btn btn-warning"></a></td>
@else
<td><a href="rejectededit/{{ $Invoice->invoicereference }}"><input type="submit" name="approved" value="Approved" class="btn btn-success"></a></td>
@endif
```

Controller Page. ( InvoicesController.php )

```
public function approvededit(Request $request, $invoicereference)
    {
        // Add Validation
        DB::table('invoices')
            ->where('invoicereference', $invoicereference)
            ->update(['invoicestatus' => 1]);
        //$request->session()->flash('Msg', 'Successfully Approved !!');
        return redirect('invoices.all-invoice');
    }
```

Route.

```
Route::get('/approvededit/{invoicereference}', 'InvoicesController@approvededit');
```

Comment: Turn on your debug mode to see what really wrong ?

Comment: @TruongDang - #53 D:\\wamp64\\www\\cheapfares\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 D:\\wamp64\\www\\cheapfares\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

Comment: http://localhost/cheapfares is this your Project URL and 
http://localhost/cheapfares/invoice/ and this is the URL where you can see all the invocie, right ?

Comment: @DsRaj - How can I do it ??

Comment: @DsRaj - http://localhost/cheapfares/invoice/all This is the URL that I can see all the invoices..

Comment: Update your route like this: Route::get('/invoice/approvededit/

Comment: What is $Invoice->invoicereference? Can you debug this?

Comment: @DsRaj - It's Working !! Thank U !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your current route  as you are using the route

http://localhost/cheapfares/invoice/approvededit/49

`approvededit(` and this is not the resource route function, so you need to add it properly

```
Route::get('/invoice/approvededit/{invoicereference}','InvoicesController@approvededit');
```

Comment: It's 100% Perfectly Working !! Thank U !! :D